# form validation not working in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, controller

```
-----IN APP CONFIG-----
$routeProvider.
        when("/", {redirectTo: "/dashboard"}).
        when("/dashboard", {template: "<div ng-include='include'>", controller="xCtrl" }).
        .otherwise({redirectTo: "/404"})

-----IN xCtrl-----
app.controller("xCtrl",function($rootScope,$scope,$filter) {
     $scope.include = "pages/abc.html";
     var original;
    $scope.filters = {p_key: ""},
    $scope.showInfoOnSubmit = !1, original = angular.copy($scope.filters),
    $scope.revert = function () {
         return $scope.filters = angular.copy(original),$scope.projectListFilters.$setPristine()
    }, $scope.canRevert = function () {
        return!angular.equals($scope.filters, original) || !$scope.projectListFilters.$pristine
    }, $scope.canSubmit = function () {
        return $scope.projectListFilters.$valid && !angular.equals($scope.filters, original)
    }, $scope.submitForm = function () {
        return $scope.showInfoOnSubmit = !0, $scope.revert()
    }
})

---- IN pages/abc.html ----

    <form name="projectListFilters" data-ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="filters.p_key" />
     <button type="submit"
            class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
            data-ng-disabled="!canSubmit()">Sumbit
    </button>
    <button id="reset" type="reset" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning"
            data-ng-disabled="!canRevert()"
            data-ng-click="revert()">Revert Changes
    </button>
    </form>
```

There are JavaScript errors in this code regarding $valid , $pristine of undefined object. But if we specify the controller in `pages/abc.html` file
Ex:
         `<form name="projectListFilters" data-ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate data-ng-controller="xCtrl">`
 works fine. What is the error in here ?

Comment: The `ng-include` create a nested child scope and the `projectListFilters` form would be on it instead of the controller's scope.

Answer (score 1):

Use `templateUrl`, not `template`.

```
{
    templateUrl: "pages/abc.html",
    controller: "xCtrl",
}
```

This will have `pages/abc.html` use `xCtrl` as its controller.  The way you are doing it now, only the `<div>` with the include has the controller, but the included page does not have it.

From [`ngInclude`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude):

> This directive creates new scope.

Comment: I need to use include because I need to get route parameters and load a template based on that parameters :(

Comment: @KalhanoToressPamuditha create a route for each template instead.  In "/dashboard" you can link to the other routes that use those templates instead of doing it the `ngInclude` way.  This should also give you more flexibility for those individual templates.

Comment: can u please describe the process a bit :) thank you :)